# wso2 dss to SQL Server connectivity using Windows authentication

Tags: wso2-data-services-server

Can someone please help me with the query shown below?

I am running DSS server in my development server. I want to connect it to my local machine's SQL Server 2014 with servername using windows authentication. I wasn't able to find any documents related to this.

I added jtds jar in the repository/components/lib folder but still getting below error

In the Dss I configured with below details but getting below error(PFA screenshot)[image: error message]

Error:

> Driver class com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver can not be loaded

Can you please help me, how to define the connection parameters in the DSS to connect my local SQL Server with Windows authentication ?

Thanks
Mahaboob

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a convoluted answer so here goes.

You can use Windows Authentication with DSS, there are many articles describing how to do this. Just google it. However, the limitation is that you must run the DSS service to impersonate a domain user, then, set the username in the connection string and, magic, the user will be impersonated and you will be connected.

Its not all good news. You will be limited to impersonating one user per DSS instance. So unless you can have a single user configured for all the SQL DB's you will use... you get the point.

The simplest way is to enable SQL Authentication. If you are in a corporate MS type shop, then your DBA'a may advise this is not a good practice. In my case, we were successful in granting special business exceptions to enable SQL Auth.

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It is due to sqlserver jar file is missing.

we have to place sqljdbc.jar file into repository\components\lib location to get rid of driver class error. please download the jar file from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

But my question still remains that how to establish a connectivity to a sqlserver using windows authentication?

[image]